# Create and Connect nodes just by using "from" and "to" info in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, data-structures, nodes

I am trying to create and connect some nodes using the array below. So in the end there would be 4 nodes connected to each other according to their from and to values. Any ideas on how to do it in React?

```
roads = [
{
    id: 1,
    from: {id: 111, name: “Company X”},
    to: {id: 222, name: “Station 1“}
},
{
    id: 2,
    from: {id: 222, name: “Station 1“},
    to: {id: 333, name: “Station 2“}
},
{
    id: 3,
    from: {id: 333, name: “Station 2”},
    to: {id: 444, name: “Company Y”}
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , you should use [Normalized State](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html#designing-a-normalized-state). It's easy way to create your Nodes ^^

Comment: But they are not very "relational".

Comment: I'm making too my App use Normalized State of Redux. 
Here is Explain of Redux. I think it 'll be helped you.
   'Because of this, the recommended approach to managing relational or 
   nested data in a Redux store is to treat a portion of your store as if it 
   were a database, and keep that data in a normalized form.

Comment: But I am not using Redux nor states.

Comment: Hmm, Because React is only Views in MVC Model, so i think you can't use only React to create your Nodes. I'm too new to React and Redux. Then wait for another Idea ^^